# Navigation using the LongListSelector Control

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, longlistselector

I have created a longlistselector using mvvm pattern.

I have created many city names under different headers.

I want to know how to navigate to a specific page when user selects or taps a particular item.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply wire up an event listener for either the `tap` event on each `ListBoxItem` (i.e. on the containing `grid` / `canvas` / whatever ) or on the `SelectionChanged` event on the list itself.

An example:

```
<ListBox:ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Tap="Tap_Handler">
            // .. your text or whatever goes here
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox:ItemTemplate>
```

and the code-behind magic:

```
public void Tap_Handler(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (sender as Grid).DataContext as City; // Given you have City objects in your list
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/City.xaml?id=" + item.Id, UriKind.Relative);
}
```

Should be something similar, if this doesn't work right out the box.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works!! only with a few changes. Instead of NavigationContext.Navigate i used NavigationService.Navigate. Edit it.

Comment: But how can i use this to navigate to different pages. For instance i've City1.xaml City2.xaml and City3.xaml. How can i navigate to these pages when user clciks City1, City2 and City3 respectively in my listselector

Comment: @user1538895 that sounded like a bad solution, but if you insist on doing that, you basically just insert the Id or whatever you have in a different location like so: "/View/City" + item.Id + ".xaml".

Comment: @user1538895 if we relate to the code above, each City-object in your LongListSelector has an Id (I presume). Then you can modify the `URI` you want to send the user to accordingly. If it doesn't you can always solve any special cases with either a switch/case statement or if/else statements.

Comment: If you feel like this answered your question, please vote up and accept as answer, as it will help others with the same problem to find a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can just subscribe to the `SelectionChanged` event from `LongListSelector`.

```
longListSelector.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(longListSelector_SelectionChanged);
```